# Wifi hotspot

Tags: android, wifi, hotspot

Можем ли мы программно подключиться к wifi hotspot точке? 
Я имею ввиду передать ей уже известные нам логин и пароль тем самым авторизировавшись там.

Comment: уточни.. а то подключится к вайфаю всегда можно =)

Comment: тут именно wifi хотспот) который ссылается на вебстраницу для авторизации)

Comment: как по мне хотспот - это просто площядка с файваем =) или жвм =) ну в общем можно чтото придумать, если скажешь что ты конкретнее хочешь, а то можно просто с браузера зайти на твою страницу и авторизироваться

Comment: Да рассматривается ситуация что мы подключены. 
Как поймать страницу и ввести лог и пас без участия юзера?

Comment: Посмотрите запрос, который отправляется на hotspot, и подделайте его.

Comment: Как? Ведь мы в поля вводим логин и пароль же.

Comment: Ставите любой снифер, например, wireshark. Авторизуетесь с компьютера, ловите в вайршарке этот запрос, подозреваю, что это будет POST. Затем формируете точно такой же запрос с телефона/таба, есть классы соответствующие.

Comment: А какого-то универсального способа нету? Разные хотспоты, разные запросы. Не снифать же все заранее

Comment: Можно, конечно, пробовать парсить страницу, искать форму и ее элементы, включая метод отправки запроса (GET или POST), и формировать свой запрос.

Comment: А пароли для всех хотспотов одинаковые чтоль? Универсальные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, программно подключиться к wi-fi можно. Это довольно заморочено зависит от кодировки ключей и проч., тем не менее сделать можно. Посмотрите дискуссию ссылки и исходники [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android)